# Any benefit for my case when using Hive as datawarehouse?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata

Currently, i am trying to adopt big data to replace my current data analysis platform. My current platform is pretty simple, my system get a lot of structured csv feed files from various upstream systems, then, we load them as java objects (i.e. in memory) for aggregation.

I am looking for using Spark to replace my java object layer for aggregation process.

I understandthat Spark support loading file from hdfs / filesystem. So, Hive as data warehouse seems not a must. However, i can still load my csv files to Hive first, then, use Spark to load data from Hive.

My question here is, in my situation, what's the pros / benefit if i introduce a Hive layer rather than directly loading the csv file to Spark DF.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to load anything. You can create external tables over hdfs / filesystem directories and query them using whatever is using the metastore, including spark.

Comment: If you are processing data as Full load and incremental way then go with Hive layer as you have to store yesterdays data in table format and process incremental with today's data . If you are only doing Extracting and Transforming and Storing it back to normal filesystem then you can use only spark.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can always look and feel the data using the tables.
2. Adhoc queries/aggregation can be performed using HiveQL.
3. When accessing that data through Spark, you need not mention the schema of the data separately.

Comment: For 2, i can use Spark SQL instead of HiveQL

Comment: Yes you can always do that but you would need to load the data from csv to dataframe/temp table and then submit the job to get the results. That would be like a batch process.
Using HiveQL, it would feel like interactive query just like u perform SQL queries.

Comment: sorry, i am new to spark. May i know if it is possible to load all csv data to dataframe as "global table" and let every user in the spark session to query it.

Comment: You can do that but do you really need all the data loaded into memory. Hive table data is persisted and all users can access the tables and use the data but I m not sure if one user load the data in memory as dataframe and can be used by all the other users and I don't like the idea.